# Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API key error

Tags: gcloud, json

I tried to use the Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API but without any success. I have an API key error.

Here is my api call :

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(myapikey) \
    https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize \
    -d @sync-request.json
```

sync-request.json content is the following :

```
{
  "config": {
      "encoding":"FLAC",
      "sampleRateHertz": 48000,
      "languageCode": "fr-FR",
      "enableWordTimeOffsets": true
  },
  "audio": {
      "uri":"gs://audio-bucket_bl/audio.flac"
  }
}
```

and result is the following :

```
-bash: myapikey: command not found
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

For your information, I took my api key from here : https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials? (Key 1 from api keys list)

Do you know what I'm doing wrong ? It's about the api key so or it's the wrong one or I do not set it in the good way.

Thank you for your help :)

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

In your command this construct

```
$(myapikey)
```

tells the shell to run the command myapikey, the output from which would be substituted in it's place e.g.

```
ls $(which chmod) -l
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 58592 Aug 20  2019 /bin/chmod
```

This explains why you see this error

```
-bash: myapikey: command not found
```

as there is no command `myapikey` (in your path). You do not need to use the `$(...)`, using

```
"$myapikey"
```

will probably work as you expect.